# Retrieve users the user didn't invite yet

Tags: php, facebook, events

As you know from the usual "Invite a friend" to a public event [example screenshot](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0cc73fj6b),
it appears to be possible to retrieve all friends that aren't yet invited one sample event.

As there is a limitation on sending invitations (100 open invitations a time), it'd be important to get this information to prevent errors and server wastement.

So, how do i get this list of not-invited friends?
If that isn't possible, how can i invite bigger friendlists to an event (can i check f.e. how many open invitations are left, or sth similiar?) ?

Please share your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do to get the list of the people not invited to the event is to:

Request both your friendslist(/me/friends) and the event invitelist(EventID/invited) with FBgraph.
Compare the two to see which ones that arent in both lists.

The resulting array will be the ones that havent been invited.